# R: sparse matrix multiplication with data.table and quanteda package?

Tags: r, matrix, data.table, sparse-matrix, quanteda

I am trying to create a matrix mulptiplication with sparse matrix and with the package called quanteda, utilising data.table package, related to this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330753/more-efficient-means-of-creating-a-corpus-and-dtm-with-4m-rows). So

```
require(quanteda) 

mytext <- c("Let the big dogs hunt", "No holds barred", "My child is an honor student")     
myMatrix <-dfm(mytext, ignoredFeatures = stopwords("english"), stem = TRUE) #a data.table
as.matrix(myMatrix) %*% transpose(as.matrix(myMatrix))
```

how can you get the matrix multiplication working here with quanteda package and sparse matrices?

Comment: @Roland quanteda returns the data.table object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
mytext <- c("Let the big dogs hunt", 
            "No holds barred", 
            "My child is an honor student")     
myMatrix <- dfm(mytext)

myMatrix %*% t(myMatrix)
## 3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
##       text1 text2 text3
## text1     5     .     .
## text2     .     3     .
## text3     .     .     6
```

No need to coerce to a dense matrix using `as.matrix()`.  Note that it is no longer a "dfmSparse" object because it's no longer a matrix of documents by features.

Answer (score 1):

Use `t` command, not `transpose` command, for the matrix multiplication such that

```
as.matrix(myMatrix) %*% t(as.matrix(myMatrix))
```

also as commented, as.matrix is non-sparse while Matrix::matrix is sparse but unnecessary here, so better

```
myMatrix %*% t(myMatrix)
```

and potentially even better

```
crossprod(myMatrix) 
tcrossprod(myMatrix)
```

but it requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments, not working with the example in the question:

```
require(quanteda)  
mytext <- c("Let the big dogs hunt", "No holds barred", "My child is an honor student")      
myMatrix <-dfm(mytext, ignoredFeatures = stopwords("english"), stem = TRUE) 
crossprod(myMatrix) 
tcrossprod(myMatrix)
```

Comment: Also, `as.matrix` will not create a sparse matrix. Use `Matrix::Matrix` instead.

Comment: @dww super important point, thank you! +1 How is `Matrix::Matrix` different from `Matrix::sparseMatrix`?

Comment: I'm not familar wth quantega, but I just installed it, and it seems that 'dfm' already returns a sparse matrix of class `dfm-class`. In which case all you need is `myMatrix %*% t(myMatrix)`. Are you using an old version of quantega that you get a data.table returned? Also in my version `ignoredFeatures` argument is ignored.

Comment: I always thought this is what we have `tcrossprod` for

Comment: @DavidArenburg can you clarify? crossprod/tcrossprod fires error about requiring numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments.